# How can you insert a colon every two characters?

Tags: r

I have a column of time values, except that they are in character format and do not have the colons to separate H, M, S.  The column looks similar to the following:

```
Time
024201
054722
213024
205022
205024
125440
```

I want to convert all the values in the column to look like actual time values in the format `H:M:S`.  The values are already in `HMS` format, so it is simply a matter of inserting colons, but that is proving more difficult than I thought.  I found a package that adds commas every three digits from the right to make Strings look like currency values, but nothing for time (without also adding a date value, which I do not want to do).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the data is time related, you should consider storing it in a POSIX format:

```
> df <- data.frame(Time=c("024201", "054722", "213024", "205022", "205024", "125440")
> df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%H%M%S")
> df

                 Time
1 2014-01-05 02:42:01
2 2014-01-05 05:47:22
3 2014-01-05 21:30:24
4 2014-01-05 20:50:22
5 2014-01-05 20:50:24
6 2014-01-05 12:54:40
```

To output just the times:

```
> format(df, "%H:%M:%S")
      Time
1 02:42:01
2 05:47:22
3 21:30:24
4 20:50:22
5 20:50:24
6 12:54:40
```

Comment: Even though the regex answers are very helpful, I like that this preserves the Time nature of the data values. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A regular expression with lookaround works for this:

```
gsub('(..)(?=.)', '\\1:', x$Time, perl=TRUE)
```

The `(?=.)` means a character (matched by `.`) must follow, but is not considered part of the match (and is not captured).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a regex solution:

```
x <- readLines(n=6)
024201
054722
213024
205022
205024
125440 

gsub("(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)

## [1] "02:42:01"  "05:47:22"  "21:30:24" 
## [4] "20:50:22"  "20:50:24"  "12:54:40 "
```

Here the `(\\d\\d)` says we're looking for 2 digits.  The parenthesis breaks the string into 3 parts.  Then the `\\1:` says take chunk 1 and place a colon after it.

Answer (score 2):

Or via date/times classes:

```
time <- c("024201", "054722", "213024", "205022", "205024", "125440")
time <- as.POSIXct(paste0("1970-01-01", time), format="%Y-%d-%m %H%M%S")
(time <- format(time, "%H:%M:%S"))
# [1] "02:42:01" "05:47:22" "21:30:24" "20:50:22" "20:50:24" "12:54:40"
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives a [chron](http://cran.r-project.org/package=chron) "times" class vector:

```
> library(chron)
> times(gsub("(..)(..)(..)", "\\1:\\2:\\3", DF$Time))
[1] 02:42:01 05:47:22 21:30:24 20:50:22 20:50:24 12:54:40
```

The "times" class can display times without having to display the date and supports various methods on the times.

On the other hand, if only a character string is wanted then only the `gsub` part is needed.