# converting numbers to time

Tags: r, time

I entered my data by hand, and to save time I didn't include any punctuation in my times. So, for example, 8:32am I entered as 832. 3:34pm I entered as 1534. I'm trying to use the 'chrono' package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/chron.pdf) in R to convert these to time format, but chrono seems to require a delimiter between the hour and minute values. How can I work around this or use another package to convert my numbers into times?

And if you'd like to criticize me for asking a question that's already been answered before, please provide a link to said answer, because I've searched and haven't been able to find it. Then criticize away.

Comment: Assuming you stored your data in a text file, wouldn't it be easier to read that data into a script, fix the delimiter issue and output the massaged data into a new text file, and then go on with your business?  Just my cents on the subject matter as I have no experience with r and the chrono package.  Cheers.

Comment: would 1:01AM be 101 or 11?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929100/how-can-you-insert-a-colon-every-two-characters/20929127#20929127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `sub` solution using a regular expression:

```
set.seed(1); times <- paste0(sample(0:23,10), sample(0:59,10)) # ex. data
sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", times) # put in delimitter
# [1] "6:12"  "8:10"  "12:39" "19:21" "4:43"  "17:27" "18:38" "11:52" "10:19" "0:57"
```

Comment: Slightly shorter equivalent: `sub("(\\d{2})$", ":\\1", times)`

Comment: Even shorter: `sub("(..)$", ":\\1", times)`

Comment: I love the 'sub' solution. For anyone else trying to figure out what what this code actually means, this should help: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 7):

I think you don't need the chron package necessarily. When:

```
x  <-  c(834, 1534)
```

Then:

```
time <- substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", x), format='%H%M'), 12, 16)
time

[1] "08:34" "15:34"
```

should give you the desired result. When you also want to include a variable which represents the date, you can use the ollowing line of code:

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$yymmdd, sprintf("%04.0f", df$x)), format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

Comment: Actually, I'm also a former cron user, converted to Postixct.  chron's reliance on decimals to represent time of day created many problems with round off errors. POSIXct's representation is an integer, which ensures values are unique.

Answer (score 2):

Say

```
x  <-  c('834', '1534')
```

The last two characters represent minutes, so you can extract them using

```
mins  <-  substr(x, nchar(x)-1, nchar(x))
```

Similarly, extract hours with

```
hour  <-  substr(x, 0, nchar(x)-2)
```

Then create a fixed vector of time values with

```
time  <-  paste0(hour, ':', mins)
```

I think you are forced to specify dates in the chron package, so assuming a date value, you can converto chron with this:

```
chron(dates.=rep('02/02/02', 2), 
      times.=paste0(hour, ':', mins, ':00'), 
      format=c(dates='m/d/y',times='h:m:s'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd throw out a non-regex solution that uses `lubridate`. This is probably overkill.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

time.orig <- c('834', '1534')

# zero pad times before noon
time.padded <- str_pad(time.orig, 4, pad="0")

# parse using lubridate
time.period <- hm(time.padded)

# make it look like time
time.pretty <- paste(hour(time.period), minute(time.period), sep=":")
```

And you end up with

```
> time.pretty
[1] "8:34"  "15:34"
```

Comment: Function hm() can not parse these strings in lubridate 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions that do not use regular expressions:

```
library(chron)
x <- c(832, 1534, 101, 110) # test data

# 1
times( sprintf( "%d:%02d:00", x %/% 100, x %% 100 ) )

# 2
times( ( x %/% 100 + x %% 100 / 60 ) / 24 )
```

Either gives the following chron `"times"` object:

```
[1] 08:32:00 15:34:00 01:01:00 01:10:00
```

*ADDED* second solution.